# Is official. the history.push doesnt render a new component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lib 5.0.0 from history.js does not render the new component with the 'push' method. It is doing port redirection but the component does not render. Before say that the subject is repeated,, I tried everything available on the internet. The 'withRouter', changing the 'history' parameter. I'm trying to put the 'push' inside the saga and using react hooks. I really don't know why of this behavior. Anyway. I am providing the code below.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './config/ReactotronConfig';
import Routes from './routes/index';
import history from './services/history';
import { store, persistor } from './store/index';
import GlobalStyle from './styles/global';

function App() {
  return (
<>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Routes />
        <GlobalStyle />
      </Router>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
   </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import Route from './Route';
import Landing from '../pages/Landing';
import Main from '../pages/Main';
import SignUp from '../pages/SignUp';
import Profile from '../pages/Profile';
import EditProfile from '../pages/EditProfile';
import SignIn from '../pages/SignIn';
import ForgotPassword from '../pages/ForgotPassword';
import ResetPassword from '../pages/ResetPassword';

export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/main" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/register" component={SignUp} />
        <Route path="/login" component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/forgot" component={ForgotPassword} />
        <Route path="/reset" component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />

        <Route path="/editprofile" component={EditProfile} isPrivate />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**routes/auth/sagas.js**

```
import { takeLatest, all, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import api from '../../../services/api';
import * as authActions from './actions';
import history from '../../../services/history';

function* login({ payload }) {
  try {
    const session = yield call(api.post, 'session', payload);
    yield put(authActions.loginSuccess(session.data));
    history.push('/main')
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(authActions.loginFailure(error));
  }
}
export default all([takeLatest('@auth/login_request', login)]);
```

Comment: try to use history from router, if yoou are using function, then `import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom". History.push will try to update that route, but not entire application. It's not same as refresh.

Comment: What does `history from './services/history'` look like? Both `Link` and `history.push()` will render/rerender the component, but they will not remount it, if that's what you're actually trying to achieve. As said above, make sure you are using `react-router-dom` history.